# How to scan ether transfer from smart contract to my addresses programmatically?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

Correct me if I am wrong, the transaction receipt contains only the log of contract events. So we can only use it to examine the internal transaction that produces a event.

How about ether transfer inside a contract? More specifically when the contract calls the `send` or `transfer` of a Members of Addresses(#1).

Let’s say I have a large list of deposit addresses, is there any general way to detect ether transfer made from a contract (it can be any contracts written by others) by scanning a transaction?

1: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#members-of-addresses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "[How to detect transfer of funds from contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31447/how-to-detect-transfer-of-funds-from-contract)".

Moreover, in the newest version of geth, there are helpful tracer scripts, which allow you to easily query "internal transactions". See https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/15516